# Unusual URL in my WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, url, admin, panel

There is *unusual url* in my WordPress website. And I'm not being able to login to WordPress *admin panel*. Can you please suggest me what this issue is about and how to solve it?

http://www.footlooseinthehimalaya.com/#sthash.2hhVAuGK.dpbs

http://www.footlooseinthehimalaya.com/about-us/#sthash.ASukK5uY.dpbs

Comment: is those URL showing after migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using **Share This** plugin? It looks like it have something to do with this unusual URL. So, if you are using Share This you can try to add `shorten:false` to your code. You will end with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({ doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false , shorten:false});</script>
```

If this doesn't work, you could try to contact Share This support to find out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  ShareThis plugin settings and find "Measure copy & shares of your site’s URLs". Enable this option and disable this option "Measure copy & shares of your site’s content" in plugin's setting page.
and wooaaaa #sthash gone........